# Connect Zimbra OS with outlook

Tags: email, ubuntu, outlook, mail-server, zimbra

I´m very new to Zimbra and setting up mail servers.
I have the requirement to create domains with email accounts, so I´ve set up a virtual machine with zimbra.
It has worked fine until I created a new domain incl. account, which I wanted to connect with outlook. 
I did this before with the host domain and it was no problem to send and retrieve mails via outlook, but with an other domain it doesn´t work.
I can access the account on the web interface.

When I try to connect with outlook it seems like it can´t find the domain name?

To sum up:

zimbra host: mail.example.local

admin@mail.example.local works with outlook

-> new domain + account in zimbra test@test.local doesn´t work with outlook

when I access test.local via browser I can login with test account.

Can anyone help me or give me an advice?

I can't find any information in the outlook log files...

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In outlook you mast set imap/pop server mail.example.local or set dns A record test.local = mail.example.local